# Chamar função em componente no React ES2016

Tags: react

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de componentes:
< game>
< board>
< cell>
</ board>
</ game>

Tenho uma função chamada Bomb() no componente game:

```
function Game(){
    ....
    function bomb(){
        console.log("e");
    }
return(
        <div className='gamePlace'>
            <Board boardName="player" />
            <Board boardName="ai" />
            <div className='clear'></div>
        </div>
    );
}

...
}
```

depois tenho o board

```
function Board(props){
    const cells = []
    for (let index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
        cells.push(<Cell key={index} id={index} />);
    }
    return(
        <div id={props.boardName} className="board">
            {cells}
        </div>
    )
}
```

e quero chamamar a função BOMB do componente Game no filho 3, no componente Cell:

```
function Cell(props){
    function bomb(id){
        Game.bomb();
    }

    return(
        <div id={props.id} className="cell" onClick={() => bomb(props.id) } ></div>
    )
}
```

como faço?
Não consigo achar uma solução.

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente, o que você precisa é passar a função "bomb" como props para os demais componentes. Veja se este exemplo te ajuda https://www.freecodecamp.org/portuguese/news/como-passar-dados-e-eventos-entre-componentes-em-react/

Comment: Não. Eu preciso chamar a sub função BOMB do componente Game a partir do terceiro subcomponente CELL, os props se perdem no caminho.

Answer (score 0):

Passando a sub função de bomb em Game até Cell por props, tipo assim:

Game.js

```
 <Board bomb={bomb} boardName="player" />
 <Board bomb={bomb} boardName="ai" />
```

---

Board.js

```
 for (let index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
   cells.push(<Cell bomb={props.bomb} key={index} id={index} />);
 }
```

---

Cell.js

```
function Cell(props){    
    return(
        <div onClick={() => props.bomb(props.id) } id={props.id} className="cell"  ></div>
    )
}
```

---

Tem outras soluções, se o componente Game fosse em classe, daria pra função bomb ser 'static' e chamar em qualquer componente através de Game.bomb(id)

Como também, sem usar classe, daria pra utilizar Context API (até mesmo um Redux) do React para passar essa função sem ser por props